# using .htaccess to password a page with no username just password and html form

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

I am very new to building websites and have been building one for the last couple months. I would no like to add a password protected page on my site which contains a library of files to download. I have already built a simple form on my homepage to use to input login details but I only want to include a password NOT a username. The problem I have is that all the current .htaccess tutorials online need both username and password and you cannot use your own login box on the site. If anyone could provide me with the code and tell me where to put it I would appreciate it.

my login box on my index.html is a simple form:

```
<form>
Member login:<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="button" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Thanks for taking a look at this,

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If will need a serverside script which checks, whether the password is correct or not.

First you have to modify your form to call the script

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  Member login:<input type="password" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Changes:

- action: defines the script which is called when user clicks the submit button
- input type=submit: the submit button which causes the form to send its data to the server
- method: defines the way the data is passed to the server

A simple example for "login.php" would be this PHP script:

```
<?php
  if($_POST["password"] == "Your password here.") {
?>
Your website here.
<?php
  }
  else
  {
?>
Error message here.
<?php
  }
?>
```

line 2 checks if the password field posted by the form equals the String on the right ("Your password here").

The text "Your website here." is shown, when the password is correct. Otherwise it will show "Error message here." You can replace that texts by regular HTML code.

In addition to your comment:

You should never redirect to an HTML file after an login, because that file has to be public for an redirection to it.
Instead you should use .htaccess to make it private (only accesible by localhost) and INCLUDE it via the php script.

.htacces to make an folder private:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

updated PHP script (secureFolder is the private folder):

```
<?php
  if($_POST["password"] == "Your password here.") {
    include("secureFolder/members.html");
  }
  else
  {
?>
Error message here.
<?php
  }
?>
```

Please be aware, that you can only access a single site this way. To allow an user to open multiple site's after an login you will need an PHP session which saves the users login and provides the pages.

Comment: That sounds like just what i need, thank you. Just one question, you say that if the password is correct "The text "Your website here." is shown". How can I ammend this code to just automatically redirect to the members.html webpage? Do I just replace the txt with the url? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Just added it to the answer ;)